# Using a Multinomial Bayes Classifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm new to python and scikit, so please bear with me if this is a stupid question. I've followed some tutorials in order to make a multinomial naive bayes classifier using sklearn, and I've trained and tested it to a decent accuracy. However, I've reached the end of the tutorials, and have realized I don't actually know how to feed new data for it to classify. Here's my code:

```
import sklearn as skl;
import pandas as pd;
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score;
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split;
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB;
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import seaborn as sns;
import numpy as np;

def print_top10(vectorizer, clf):
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    class_labels = clf.classes_
    for i, class_label in enumerate(class_labels):
        top10 = np.argsort(clf.coef_[0])[-10:]
        print("%s: %s" % (class_label,
              " ".join(feature_names[j] for j in top10)))

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Nicholas\vegas700.xlsx');

#edit:
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Nicholas\vegasunlabeled.xlsx');

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['text'], df['label'], random_state=11, test_size=0.25);

#edit:
finalx_train, finalx_test, finaly_train, finaly_test = train_test_split(df['text'], df['label'], random_state=1, test_size=0.99)

cv = CountVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii', token_pattern=u'(?ui)\\b\\w*[a-z]+\\w*\\b', lowercase=True, stop_words='english');

X_train_cv = cv.fit_transform(X_train.values.astype('U'));
X_test_cv = cv.transform(X_test.values.astype('U'));
#edit:
finalx_cv = cv.transform(finalx_test.values.astype('U'));

print("training...");
mnb = MultinomialNB();
mnb.fit(X_train_cv, y_train);
#edit:
new_predictions = mnb.predict_log_proba(finalx_cv)
print(new_predictions)
```

How do I use/give my classifier a new data set, and how do I get it to give me the percentage appearance of each class in that new set?

Edit:
`vegas700.xlsx` has three columns: in order from left to right they are called `'id'`, `'text'`, and `'label'`. `id` is just the item number, `text` is the text, and `label` is a class, either 0 or 1.

After adding the new lines of code, I get a result of:

```
[[-8.24928263e+00 -2.61480227e-04]
 [-4.33474053e+00 -1.31919059e-02]
 [-3.81104731e+00 -2.23734239e-02]
 ...
 [-1.62156753e-04 -8.72702816e+00]
 [-3.35454988e+00 -3.55495505e-02]
 [-1.16414198e-01 -2.20824326e+00]]
```

I have no idea what this means, and no idea if it is correct.

Comment: Try `mnb.predict(new_dataset)`. By the way, you do not need to use `;` at the end of each line.

Comment: @moys what form should the new dataset be in? should it be a pandas dataframe? or a raw excel file? also sorry about the `;`, it's a habit from java

Comment: It should be in the same form as `X_train` that you have used to train the model (even the same columns as the X_train)

Comment: @moys I've realized that's what I need to figure out how to do. I'm not sure what form exactly X_train is, but the `vegas700.xlsx` and `vegasunlabeled.xlsx` files are in the exact same format. I assume that doing another `train_test_split` on `vegasunlabeled` isn't the right way to go about it, but I don't really understand what X_train is.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is using predict_log_proba instead of just predict. What you are seeing is the log of the probability that each sample is 0 or 1, which is helpful if you want to see how "sure" your model is of each label. If you only want to see the labels themselves, use predict. More info [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html).

Edit: Since this is a simple two class problem, you just need to sum the predicted outputs and divide by the shape for the percentage of samples labeled 1:

```
preds = mnb.predict(x)
print(100*preds.sum()/len(preds))
```

One more suggestion for expanding to new datasets, I would look into the [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) feature of sklearn. That way you can create a pipeline that incorporates any transformations and quickly go from file to new dataset to predict on. Also, you don't need the train test split for the new data.